# How to display in Woocommerce product page if a product is Digital

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How should I highlight on my product pages if the specific item is downloadable? I want to create something like Etsy made on their Digital Products, so on my product page if the selected product is digital I want to display a notice. Something like "This is a digital product, different policies apply..." And on physical (non-digital) products I don't want to show this notice. I think I need to do something with the functions.php but I don't know how to achieve this outcome. Do you have any idea? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this snippet for notice on digital product

```
function display_digital_product_notice() {
    global $product;

    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) && $product->is_downloadable() ) {
        echo '<div class="digital-product-notice">This is a digital product.</div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'display_digital_product_notice' );
```

Comment: Thank You! This is just what I looked for. Works like a charm.